# sql return data not seen as integer

Tags: php, mysql

When i run:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<li><a href=index.php>" . $row['item'] . "</a></li>"  . $row['comment'] . " " ;

    if (is_int($row['price'])) {
        echo $row['price'] . " naira" . "<br>";
    }else{
        echo $row['price'] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Where "price" was set as a varchar and contains integers in some fields and text in others, it reads them all the same way and nothing is seen as an integer. Could it be a config I'm missing while creating the table because I dont see anything wrong with this code?

Comment: is_int() will strictly detect only integers. However,  if you want to detect numerics, use is_numeric() instead

Comment: one more thing, I don't think mysql_fetch_array() will return int-type variables (same with fetch_assoc()). The best way for you to check for data types is to use fetch_fields() http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_field

or simply, use type-casting if you're really expecting them to be int

finally, mysql_ is no longer recommended.. Use mysqli_ instead, or better, pdo

Comment: Ronald Borla solved my issue but i cant select his as the right answer and mysqli isnt working out for me...it gives me errors and i dunno why

Comment: Try install `mysqlnd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
if(intval($row['price']) > 0) { ... }
```

or

```
if(is_numeric($row['price'])) { ... }
```